# Eclipse Galileo and ADT plugin

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I cannot get this to install. I went through the other threads here and followed the workarounds but still not.

i have eclipse 3.5.2 galileo. i also did an uninstall and re-install via the ubuntu(10.4) software centre. I downloaded the ADT-16.0.1.zip and tried to add it to the availble sites.

when i try and install from Android Developer Tools - https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534)
  Missing requirement: Android Traceview 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534 (com.android.ide.eclipse.traceview.feature.group 16.0.1.v201112150204-238534) requires 'org.eclipse.ui 3.6.2' but it could not be found

nothing want to work.
please help?
thanks

Comment: Maybe you would want to switch to a newer version of eclipse. The newest versions of ADT only support for eclipse 3.6 or higher.
Refer http://developer.android.com/sdk/requirements.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated right on the ADT web page:

- *Eclipse Helios (Version 3.6) or higher is required for ADT 16.0.1.*

The first recommendation is to NOT install Eclipse from any Linux package manager or software repository. Instead, just get it from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/. The builds that linux distro's install are often modified (mangled, some would say).

The particular error you're getting is because ADT requires a later version of Eclipse than Ubuntu is giving you. Getting one of the packages directly from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/ will solve that, along with knowing exactly what you've got (as opposed to relying on whoever assembled the package for Ubuntu).

Answer (score 0):

I've actually done something similar this morning and worked ok:

- Ubuntu 10 64-bit
- downloaded and unzipped Eclipse indigo 64 bit
- downloaded and isntalled Oracle JDK 1.6 64bit
- added java exec to path and created proper JAVA_HOME env var
- in Eclipse:
- help->install new software
- added https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
- told it to also download the Android SDK
- all went ok
- from avd manager added Android 2.2 and 4.0.x runtimes
- started emulator, all working.